# SSl certificate for testing purpose

Tags: apache, ssl, https, openssl, xampp

I am following this link ( http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-ssl-encrypt-passwords ) for enable self signed certificate. It is works fine in my website's home page. but login to another webpage it shows "Your connection to localhost is encrypted with 128-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and can be modified by an attacker to change the behavoiur of the page.The connection uses TLS1.2 " . Also I am accessing phpmyadmin it shows same,  but accessing XAMPP folders and other php files it works fine. How can I resolve it? Plz help me...

Answer (score 1):

you can use [this](http://www.whynopadlock.com) to check which are unsecured.
just make sure to use https on every link that you have on your website, that should fix it.